# Custom JTable cell editor using my own component

Tags: java, swing, jtable, editor

I am creating an inventory type program, I have to customize `JTable` inside a `Commande` class.

The Table have 4 columns and 10 empty rows. For the first column I want to set a custom components of type `fournisseurUi` witch is a `JFrame` derived class (Constains many components).

When the user start editing, I want an editable `JComboBox` to appear, after that an instance of `fournisseurUi` needs to Popup in the position of Table cell left corner, and I must not to be movable.

Here is an image that illustrated what I want to achieve.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gulfup.com](http://im46.gulfup.com/09ZuBG.png))</sub>

Her is my code so far,

```
package VIEW.dataManager;

import VIEW.FournisseurUi;
import VIEW.SearchFounisseurUi;
import VIEW.SearchProduitUi;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;


public class myTableCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    implements TableCellEditor ,ActionListener{

    private SearchFounisseurUi Popup;
    private JButton editorComponent;
    private String value ="debut"; 

    public myTableCellEditor(JComboBox jcb) {
        super(jcb);
        editorComponent = new JButton();
        editorComponent.setActionCommand("change");
        editorComponent.setBackground(Color.yellow);          
        Popup = SearchFounisseurUi.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable jtable, Object o, boolean bln, int i, int i1) {

        value = "editor";
        return Popup;

    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("change".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            Popup.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("preformed");
            fireEditingStopped();
        }
     }










}
```

In the Main class, I have used the custom Editor:

```
bonDachatTable.setDefaultEditor(String.class, new myTableCellEditor(new JComboBox()));
```

I got this little error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:488)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1089)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:415)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editCellAt(JTable.java:3520)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.adjustSelection(BasicTableUI.java:1108)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:1038)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6524)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4530)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:488)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1089)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:415)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editCellAt(JTable.java:3520)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.adjustSelection(BasicTableUI.java:1108)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:1038)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6524)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4530)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. In its current form your question is unanswerable, because it is too broad. You just dumped your task here. You don't show what you have tried so far or what your problem exactly is. Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27752850/edit) your post.

Comment: That's actually rather difficult to manage.  You need to become responsible for dismissing the popup when the cell editor is dismissed (lost of focus for some reason).  You need to be able keep the window above the current window but without affect other windows as well as define what should happen if the parent window loses focus...

Comment: You also need to overcome the JTables default focus lost process which generally cancels table editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> after that an instance of fournisseurUi needs to Popup in the position of Table cell left corner, and I must not to be movable.

Not sure if this will help. It shows an example of popping up a JDialog with a JTextArea as an editor for the cell. It doesn't do exactly what you want since you want to display a combo box first, but maybe it will give you some more ideas:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/*
 * The editor button that brings up the dialog.
 */
//public class TablePopupEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
public class TablePopupEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    implements TableCellEditor
{
    private PopupDialog popup;
    private String currentText = "";
    private JButton editorComponent;

    public TablePopupEditor()
    {
        super(new JTextField());

        setClickCountToStart(1);

        //  Use a JButton as the editor component

        editorComponent = new JButton();
        editorComponent.setBackground(Color.white);
        editorComponent.setBorderPainted(false);
        editorComponent.setContentAreaFilled( false );

        // Make sure focus goes back to the table when the dialog is closed
        editorComponent.setFocusable( false );

        //  Set up the dialog where we do the actual editing

        popup = new PopupDialog();
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return currentText;
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                popup.setText( currentText );
//              popup.setLocationRelativeTo( editorComponent );
                Point p = editorComponent.getLocationOnScreen();
                popup.setLocation(p.x, p.y + editorComponent.getSize().height);
                popup.show();
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });

        currentText = value.toString();
        editorComponent.setText( currentText );
        return editorComponent;
    }

    /*
    *   Simple dialog containing the actual editing component
    */
    class PopupDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener
    {
        private JTextArea textArea;

        public PopupDialog()
        {
            super((Frame)null, "Change Description", true);

            textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
            textArea.setLineWrap( true );
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
            KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
            textArea.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, "none");
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
            getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

            JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancel.addActionListener( this );
            JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
            ok.setPreferredSize( cancel.getPreferredSize() );
            ok.addActionListener( this );

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.add( ok );
            buttons.add( cancel );
            getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            pack();

            getRootPane().setDefaultButton( ok );
        }

        public void setText(String text)
        {
            textArea.setText( text );
        }

        /*
        *   Save the changed text before hiding the popup
        */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if ("Ok".equals( e.getActionCommand() ) )
            {
                currentText = textArea.getText();
            }

            textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
            setVisible( false );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Item", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Item 1", "Description of Item 1"},
            {"Item 2", "Description of Item 2"},
            {"Item 3", "Description of Item 3"}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(300);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // Use the popup editor on the second column

        TablePopupEditor popupEditor = new TablePopupEditor();
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor( popupEditor );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup Editor Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add( scrollPane );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```